# Consulta Sql con problemas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
select A.AuxstockArrProductoId, B.ProductoNombre, (A.AuxstockArrSubctaCant)as total 
from AuxSctaStockArr A
    inner join Producto B on A.AuxstockArrProductoId = B.ProductoId
group by A.AuxstockArrProductoId
having sum(A.AuxstockArrSubctaCant) > 0
order by A.AuxstockArrProductoId
```

Necesito agregar al lado del copdigo del producto, el nombre del mismo, pero me sale un error en la consulta que dice :

> Mens. 8120, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1 Column
>   'Producto.ProductoNombre' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Alguien que me pueda indicar como se podría agregar el nombre del producto en esta consulta por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola el error que te esta marcando es que te esta faltando agregar ProductoNombre en el Group by de tu consulta SQL, debes indicar todos los campos.
group by A.AuxstockArrProductoId,  B.ProductoNombre, total
Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado, me resulto muy útil tu información. Saludos

Comment: Tener en cuenta que falta el sum en la lista de campos del select, aunque si está en el having.